# How do I transition from one image to another by changing state in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two images with little difference between them and each corresponding to a particular state. I need to smoothly transition from one to the other when I change the state so that the effect feels like only the part which is different in the two images has undergone animation,the rest of the image staying as it is.
[image: First]

[image: Second]

I want it to work so that when I render the second image on stateChange, only the rod like part in the second image appears to fade in,the rest remaining still.

I think this can be achieved without using any animation libraries like `react-transition-group` probably by using some of the life cycle methods in React and obviously, the AnimatedAPI. The major issue that I am facing is that when I update the state I have no control over the previous image that was rendered. I somehow want the previously rendered image to stay until newly rendered Component appears and does its animation. Here is what I tried to do. I have this ImageLoader Component which renders an image while providing a fading-in animation to it.

```
class ImageLoader extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.opacity= new Animated.Value(0)
   }

    componentDidUpdate(){
   {this.onLoad()}

   } 

    onLoad = () => {
      this.opacity.setValue(0);
      Animated.timing(this.opacity, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.Image onLoad={this.onLoad}{...this.props}style={[
          {opacity: this.opacity,}, this.props.style,
       ]} 
     />
    );
  }
 }



export default class App extends React.Component {
 state={
 no:1,
}

  render() {
  let Dun=()=>{return this.state.no==1?
   <ImageLoader source={require('./assets/img1.PNG')}/>: <ImageLoader 

     source={require('./assets/img2.PNG')}/>
    }
   const calc=()=>{
   this.setState((state)=>({no:Math.abs(state.no-1)}));
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{height:100,marginLeft:50}}>

    {Dun()}

    <Button onPress={()=>{calc()}}> Press</Button>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 animated images to give the impression that one is fading into the other. Here is a solution based on your example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

import images from 'src/images';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  }
});

class ImageSwitcher extends React.Component {
  fadeInOpacity = new Animated.Value(0);

  fadeOutOpacity = new Animated.Value(1);

  state = {
    prevSource: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onLoad();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.onLoad();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ source: newSource }) {
    const { source } = this.props;
    if (newSource !== source) {
      this.setState({ prevSource: source });
    }
  }

  onLoad = () => {
    this.fadeInOpacity.setValue(0);
    this.fadeOutOpacity.setValue(1);

    Animated.timing(this.fadeInOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(this.fadeOutOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  };

  render() {
    const { prevSource } = this.state;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        }}
      >
        <Animated.Image {...this.props} style={[styles.image, { opacity: this.fadeInOpacity }]} resizeMode="cover" />
        {prevSource && (
          <Animated.Image {...this.props} style={[styles.image, { opacity: this.fadeOutOpacity }]} resizeMode="cover" source={prevSource} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    source: images.first
  };

  handleToggle = () => this.setState(({ source }) => ({ source: source === images.first ? images.second : images.first }));

  render() {
    const { source } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ImageSwitcher source={source} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleToggle}>
          <Text>Toggle Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Could I use this if I had say, 6 images that I wanted to display like this one after the other?

Comment: Why not. Just have it progress to the next source after the previous animation finishes. `Animated.timing().start(callback)` takes an optional callback if you want to start the next animation right after

Answer (score 0):

```
const SwitchImage = (props) => {
const [previousImage, setPreviousImage] = useState('');
const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

useEffect(()=>{
    Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.spring,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start(()=>{
        setPreviousImage(props.source);
        opacity.setValue(0);
    })
}, [props.source])

return(
    <View style={{width: props.style.width, height: props.style.height}}>
        <FastImage
        resizeMode={props.resizeMode}
        source={previousImage}
        style={{width: props.style.width, height: props.style.height, position: 'absolute'}}
        />
        <Animated.View style={{opacity: opacity}}>
            <FastImage
            resizeMode={props.resizeMode}
            source={props.source}
            style={{width: props.style.width, height: props.style.height, position: 'absolute'}}
            />
        </Animated.View>
    </View>
)}
```